# How do I control the height of a bootstrap select without using bootstrap-select

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am using bootstrap but not the bootstrap-select plugin. I am stating that because all the answers I have found are for bootstrap-select. I am forced to use bootstrap and I don't realy want to add another plugin on top.
Here is an example of my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="active">Year</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span  class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <select class="form-control input-sm">
            <option value="1" selected>April</option>
            <option value="2">May</option>
            <option value="3">June</option>
            <option value="4">July</option>
            <option value="5">August</option>
            <option value="6">September</option>
            <option value="7">October</option>
            <option value="8">November</option>
            <option value="9">December</option>
            <option value="10">January</option>
            <option value="11">February</option>
            <option value="12">March</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is how do I limit the height of the select dropdown?

I have tried using css, and everything. I have read many posts on the site which I have tried and nothing seems to work.